# Transition out from a 'forwards' keyframe animation?

Tags: html, css

I created a keyframe animation with CSS, 
it resizes a div to a given size and I want it to transition back to the normal size afterwards.

The problem is that the element will simply jump back to it's original size, even though it has a 'transition' property set to 'all'.

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-animation: test 200ms forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    from {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }
    to {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ordcva2/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that css animation !== css transition. Animations are for expressing changes throughout the course of mutliple frames, a transition is a simple *a* to *b* animation. As such, the two properties, though used for similar purposes do not relate to the same process.

If you are simply 'animating' the start and end points of scalable properties, you want to only use a transition:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7ordcva2/1/)

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease;
}
div:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

To accomplish this using animations alone, you would use:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7ordcva2/2/)

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-animation: out 200ms forwards;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-animation: in 200ms forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes in {
    from {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }
    to {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out {
    from {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
    to {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about this use, but I'm willing to have a multiple step animation on hover, then transition back. I suppose it isn't possible then?

Comment: @Don - it wasnt clear from your question, and you are still mixing animations and transitions (they do not interact) which isnt correct. See http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7ordcva2/2/ for animation only

Comment: Another reason why I wanted to use Transition, is that it doesn't jump to the 'from' value, like the keyframe animation does. is it possible to have the keyframe animation begin animating towards the values of 'to' from any set value?